# Add number everytime a "for{}" statement is called

Tags: javascript, math

I have a for statement inside a function like so:

```
for(i=0;i<=nc;i++){
var nd = //how many times this for statement has run+1
//if the for statement runs for the first time nd would be 1, second time nd would be 2, the for statement will run a total of "nc" times
this.id=nd }
```

How would i accomplish this?

Comment: What do you mean how many times it's run? If you want the number of iterations completed, just use `i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you mean like that ?

```
for(i=0;i<=nc;i++){
   var nd = i+1;
   this.id=nd;
}
```

Comment: In that case, why not just do `this.id=i+1` directly? It seems like a waste to create a new variable each iteration to store it like that (unless of cource nd is used a lot in the loop)

Comment: @galaxyAbstractor what if he want to use it multiple times he will not have to do `i+1` each time

Comment: it's just a copy of `i`, creating unnecessary variable

Comment: worked perfect. Will accept this answer in 3 Minutes, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve with that

```
for(i=0;i<=nc;i++)
{
   this.id = i+1; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

declare nd outside of the function

```
var nd = 0;
function...
    nd++;
    this.id = nd;
```